# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(undefined ?? 'default');
```

Why am I getting an error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Comment: try to replace ?? with ||

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The [nullish-coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator was added in [ECMAScript 11](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/).

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```js
let x = undefined; 
console.log(x ?? 'default');

x = null; 
console.log(x ?? 'default');
```

---

**Original answer**

Currently, there is no `??` operator in javascript.

You can use the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator:

```js
let x = undefined; 
console.log(x == undefined ? 'default' : x);
```

which will print `'default'` if `x` is undefined, otherwise, it will print the value of `x`.

However, you've found the proposal for the [nullish coalescing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing/) operator.  This is currently a proposal in stage 3, but it looks like it will make it into a future version of the ECMAScript.

Comment: what about this operator:  ?.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in @Uncle's comment, that feature is only a proposal at this point and is not currently implemented in Javascript. To use it before it is implemented in modern browsers, you'll need to add this Babel plugin: [@babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator).