# Why am I getting this weird error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Node.js. When I `const Discord = require("discord.js")`, I get this weird error:

```
/home/runner/HelperBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

I can't find a way to fix it, but help would be appreciated.
By the way, I'm on replit.

Comment: `??` is modern JS syntax for the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), so your error is telling you that your version of Node doesn't understand this syntax. Time to upgrade to the current LTS version of Node (14.17.6 at the time of this comment), which supports `??` just fine.

Comment: Yes, that will work in node 14+ but not in 12 if that's what you're using

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans please post this as an answer...then you'll get my upvote...comments shouldn't provide answers to questions.

Comment: Honestly? There's not much of an answer here, the error is already quite clear: there's a syntax error for valid JS syntax, so the first conclusion is "this is an old interpreter".

Comment: Yeah...but it should still be an answer, because then people will see that the question has been answered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144825/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discord.js docs say that you need to have node.js v16 or later. Head over to nodejs.org and grab the latest release (or if you're using a node version manager then update to v16 or later that way)