# How to solve error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'" while connecting Mongoo db using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using **mongodb** with **nodejs**. I have created server and make database connection file. But I am facing issue.

**Server.js file**

```
const http = require('http');

require("./config/dbConnect")

const app = require('./app/app');
// If env not containing variable then 2020 port used
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 2020;

//Server Created
const serevr = http.createServer(app);
serevr.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

**dbConnect.js file**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const dbConnect = async() => {
try {
    // await mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@lms.yy6o4yl.mongodb.net/lms?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/collectionName", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log('DB connected successfully');
} catch (error) {
    console.log("DB connection Failed", error.message);
}
};

dbConnect();
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144825/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: what is your node version. u need node 14 or above for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

Comment: I hope that wasn't your real username and password.  If they were, you should change that since it has been shared with the entire internet.

Comment: Thanks it was node version issue. Currently I was using node version 12 now I updated to 20 its working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it was node version issue. Currently I was using node version 12 now I updated to 20 its working